# Why doesn't it display the file path?

Tags: url, visual-studio-code, sass, intellisense

IntelliSense does not prompt me for the file (image) path.
I tried to install plugins, look at the settings, but I can't find anything sensible.

I'm using the **syler.sass-indented** plugin

**P.S:** I noticed this problem only with sass.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation on `url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()), you must wrap your file path inside single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) when using the CSS `url()` function.

Instead of writing:

```css
.page {
  background-image: url(../foo.png);
}
```

You need to write:

```css
.page {
  background-image: url("../foo.png");
}
```

When you wrap your file path in quotes and you type `../`, VS Code will start giving auto-complete suggestions:

[image: intellisense]

Comment: in **css** syntax, **scss**: path works even without brackets. only faced this problem in **sass**.

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me that :) May I ask does IntelliSense works previously when you omit the single or double quotes? I'll retract my answer if that works for you previously

Comment: it makes no difference whether there are quotes or not. IntelliSense displays everything correctly. this problem is most likely a sass extension.

Comment: developer answer - syler.sass-indented plugin: i'm sorry you cannot do that at the moment, feel free to open a new issue on github but its unlikely that i will add that feature since im currently only maintaining the extension and im not adding new features.